# Calculate SUM of a property in list

Tags: c#, linq, sum

I have following class:

```
public class Summary
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Marks { get; set; }
}
```

With Sample Data

```
SummaryList.Add(new ActivitySummary() { Name = "ATT",  Marks = "200"});
SummaryList.Add(new ActivitySummary() { Name =  "CHARTER",  Marks ="600"});
```

I want to add another List item to the list that would contain Total of Marks property.

```
SummaryList.Add(new ActivitySummary() { Name =  "TOTAL",  Marks ="800"});
```

How can I calculate the SUM of Marks property using LINQ?

Comment: I would change the field `Marks` to either an int, double, etc.. and use `.Sum()` on all fields. Either that or parse them, add them to a list and use sum on that. Let me know if you need an example

Comment: @RandomStranger I'd convert to Int. There is some limitation, I can't make this an int. Example please?

Comment: You need something like SummaryList.Select(activitySummary=>  Int32.Parse(activitySummary.Marks)).ToList().Sum();

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to calculate a sum, use `Sum`:

```
SummaryList.Add(new ActivitySummary() {
    Name =  "TOTAL",
    Marks = SummaryList.Sum(item => Convert.ToInt32(item.Marks)).ToString()
});
```

If your `Marks` property only contains integer numbers, making it of type `string` makes no sense. You can simplify the query if it is of type `int`:

```
public class Summary
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Marks { get; set; }
}

SummaryList.Add(new ActivitySummary() {
    Name =  "TOTAL",
    Marks = SummaryList.Sum(item => item.Marks)
});
```

If your `Marks` property is not an integer number, use `decimal`, `float` or `double` instead of `int` (and `Convert.ToDecimal`, `Convert.ToSingle` and `Convert.ToDouble` respectively).

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I would change your `Marks` attribute from a string to an int. (Double works too, but your example only shows integers).

So it would look like this:

```
public class Summary
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Marks { get; set; }
}
```

Then if you have a list of Summary objects (In your example called `SummaryList`), you can calculate a sum like this:

You will have to use `.Select(...)` in order to isolate an IEnumerable containing all Marks in a list. Afterwards, you can use `.Sum(...)` in order to sum up all these values.

```
double sum = SummaryList.Select(x => x.Marks).Sum();
```

And in the end you can add the final summary like so:

```
SummaryList.Add(new Summary() { Name = "TOTAL", Marks = sum });
```

I'm sure there are other (better) ways to do so, but this one is in my opinion fairly simple to understand.

**Edit:** I just read that you can't change it to an int, so I would use Sefe's answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<ActivitySummary> SummaryList = new List<ActivitySummary>();

            SummaryList.Add(new ActivitySummary() { Name = "ATT", Marks = "200" });
            SummaryList.Add(new ActivitySummary() { Name = "CHARTER", Marks = "600" });

            int total = SummaryList.Select(x => int.Parse(x.Marks)).Sum();
            SummaryList.Add(new ActivitySummary() { Name = "TOTAL", Marks = total.ToString() });
        }
    }
    public class ActivitySummary
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Marks { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can change Marks in ActivitySummary from a string to an int so you don't have to convert.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following :

```
    SummaryList.Add(new SummaryActivity() { Name = "TOTAL",Total = SummaryList.Sum( x=>Convert.ToDouble( x.Marks) ) });
```

Comment: Why would you introduce a new property for the total?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback I misunderstood the question