# Adding a sum to a list instead of a count

Tags: c#, linq, sum

I'm using ASP.Net Core 3.1 to develop a web app.  We need to return a list of values to a View.  The list includes counts and sums of data.  We have created a ViewModel to help. It looks like this:

```
public class ObjectCountViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Count")]
    public decimal Count { get; set; }

}
```

We created a list in the Controller to return the values.  It looks like this:

```
  List<ObjectCountViewModel> objectCounts = new List<ObjectCountViewModel>();
```

Next we added values to the list like this:

```
int itemsToCount = objects.Where(e => e.ObjectItems.Where(ep => ep.ObjectItemType.Description.Contains("ItemToCount") && ep.ObjectItemSelctionType.Description.Contains("Taken")).Count()>0).Count();
            
objectCounts.Add(new ObjectCountViewModel() { Description = "Items Counted", Count = itemsToCount });
```

This code works great!  But we also need to generate a sum.  this will be used to count items with a decimal  I can't get a sum to work.  Here is one of the solutions I have tried:

```
decimal itemToSum = objects.Where(e => e.ObjectItems.Where(ep => ep.ObjectItemType.Description.Contains("ItemToSum") && ep.ObjectItemSelectionType.Description.Contains("Taken") && ep.ObjectValueAmount>0).Sum()>0).Sum();
            
objectCounts.Add(new ObjectCountViewModel() { Description = "Items Taken Sum", Count = itemToSum });
```

I have received a wide variety of errors.  The current one is:  'IEnumerable' does not contain a definition for 'Sum' and the best extension method overload 'ParallelEnumerable.Sum(ParallelQuery)' requires a receiver type of 'ParallelQuery,decimal>.

What am I doing wrong?  What should my query look like for a sum?

Comment: You can only sum numbers; you're trying to sum `objects`. Decide what property it is you want to sum, and select that item, using [`Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=net-6.0). Also, it's better to use `.Any()` rather than `.Count() > 0`. `.Count()` has to go through the whole list to count all of them, `.Any()` stops after the first one.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I refactored and came up with the code below.  The error remains.  Am I putting the Select statement in the wrong place?                         
                                                                                                                               
decimal itemToSum =  objects.Where(e => e.ObjectItems.Where(ep => ep.ObjectItemType.Description.Contains("ItemToSum") && ep.ObjectItemSelectionType.Description.Contains("Taken")).Select(ep=>ep.ItemValueAmount).Any()).Sum();

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculate SUM of a property in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41439356/calculate-sum-of-a-property-in-list)

Comment: Indeed, the `Select` should come after/outside the `Where`, just before the `.Sum()`

Comment: Thanks for your help, Heretic Monkey.  I got it working now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a list of lists, where you want to count all lists, then use `listsOfList.SelectMany(x=>x).Count()`.

If you have a list of decimals, where you want a sum of all decimals, then use `listsOfDecimals.Sum()`.

If you have a list of lists of decimals, where you want a sum of all decimals, then use `listsOfListOfDecimals.SelectMany(x=>x).Sum()`.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer thanks to Heretic Monkey and Intellisense.  I had to create a new object with the value I'm trying to sum and then filter to only select from ones that met my criteria.  Then, I separated the Select statement from the Where Clause as Heretic Monkey said. Intellisense suggested I put (decimal) in front of the whole thing, and it worked! Here is my final code for this problem.

```
decimal itemToSum = (decimal)Objects.Where(ep => ep.RelatedObjectType.Description.Contains("Description") && ep.DifferentRelatedObjectType.Description.Contains("Description")).Select(ep => ep.itemToSum).Sum();
```